# Creating new Role in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement

I want to write an IF Condition in PostgresQL which will CREATE a new ROLE in the DB, but should work in such a way that.

I first check in an IF statement if the existing user has the privilege to CREATE a new ROLE and if the user has the privilege only then execute the CREATE ROLE statement.

Something like

```
IF ( Current user has privilege to create new ROLE ) THEN
   CREATE ROLE rolename;
end if;
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

I would simply try an run the `create role` statement and let it fail, notifying whoever runs the script that something went wrong.

However, you can do what you want by checking if the current user has the `createrole` privilege:

```
do
$$
begin
  if (select rolcreaterole 
      from pg_roles
      where rolname = current_user) then 

     create role rolename;
  end if;
end;
$$
;
```

Comment: Thanks you @a_horse_with_no_name